# Binary matrix vector multiplication

Tags: c, vector, matrix, binary-matrix

I want to multiply a 8x8 *binary* matrix represented as a unsigned 64 bit integer by a 8 bit vector represented by a unsigned char. However, due to some other issues the matrix **must be** ordered by columns, ergo there's no easy matching of bytes for easy multiplication.

Any idea how to speed up such a calculation? Every operation counts for I need billions of such calculations made.

The multiplications are made over a 2 element field (F-2).

Comment: Can you give an example of (slow) code? What is your current speed? Do you target the modern x86/x86_64?

Comment: running on 64 bit architecture -- the slow code is a direct translation from F-7, so it multiplies bit by bit.

Comment: Is the operation `result= vector*matrix` or `result= matrix*vector`? Posting the naive version would help, because I think you can reduce it to `output[bit]= vector[bit] && matrix_row[bit]!=0`.

Comment: @MSN, the whole point was to avoid `[bit]` indexing.

Comment: @Kornel, right, but if you are just doing that you can then use SWAR techniques to do bit operations in parallel. (SIMD Within A Register.) Which is what Peter G. Did.

Comment: @MSN, no need anymore, I did the calculations already (it was checking a set of graphs for a math paper) -- still, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this matrix and vector representation, it helps to do matrix multiplication this way:

(col<sub>1</sub> ... col<sub>8</sub>) * (v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>8</sub>)<sup>T</sup> = col<sub>1</sub> * v<sub>1</sub> + ... + col<sub>8</sub> * v<sub>8</sub>

where matrix A = (col<sub>1</sub> ... col<sub>8</sub>)

and column vector v = (v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>8</sub>)<sup>T</sup>

Thinking this further, you can do all multiplications at once if you inflate the 8-bit vector to a 64-bit vector by repeating every bit 8 times and then calculating `P = A & v_inflated`. The only thing left then, is the addition (i.e. XOR) of the products.

A simple approach for XORing the products is.

```
uint64_t P = calculated products from text above;
uint64_t sum = 0;
for( int i = 8; i; --i )
{
   sum ^= P & 0xFF;
   P >> 8;  
}
```

Comment: You can optimize sum further with: `P^= P>>32; P^= P>>16; P^= P>>8; sum= P & 0xff;`

Answer (score 6):

You ONLY HAVE 256 vectors! Use lookup tables to generate the right bitmasks, then your logic will be something like

```
output_bit_n = bool (matrix [n] & lookup [vector])
```

In other words, your lookup table can transpose an 8-bit value into the 64-bit world.

You can efficiently pack this into the result with [rotate-with-carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) instructions if the compiler isn't smart enough to optimise `(value<<=1)|=result`.

Comment: +1: while this is helpful advice it's the one with the column based multiplication that made the most difference, still - thank you!